# Zend_Dom_Query_Result methods list?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Where can I found the class Zend_Dom_Query_Result methods list? 
Untill now I have the getAttribute() method, but I cannot find the others in the documentation?
The getAttribute method can be used to get an elements attributes, but how can I get the elements text?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.6/Zend_Dom/Query/Zend_Dom_Query_Result.html

Comment: Unfortunately it is not this, but the ones, where the getAttribute() is member too. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Zoli Why not? This IS the method list from the official doc.

Comment: Maybee I dont asked the right question. Anyway I'll mark your answer as the solution. Thanks!